# Grails - NullPointerException related to beforeInsert and Boolean assignment

Tags: grails, nullpointerexception, boolean

I have to write a class to register values which need to be compared to a maximum value and then assign the truth result to another variable. Consider the following domain class:

```
class SoManyBooleans{
    BigDecimal valueOne
    BigDecimal valueOneMaximum
    Boolean valueOneCorrect=true

    BigDecimal valueTwo
    BigDecimal valueTwoMaximum
    Boolean valueTwoCorrect=true

    BigDecimal valueThree
    BigDecimal valueThreeMaximum
    Boolean valueThreeCorrect=true
    .
    .
    .   
    BigDecimal valueNinetyNine
    BigDecimal valueNinetyNineMaximum
    Boolean valueNinetyNineCorrect=true

    Boolean allValuesCorrect

    static constraints = {
        valueOne()
        valueOneMaximum()
        valueOneCorrect()

        valueTwo()
        valueTwoMaximum()
        valueTwoCorrect()

        valueThree()
        valueThreeMaximum()
        valueThreeCorrect()     
        .
        .
        .   
        valueNinetyNine()
        valueNinetyNineMaximum()
        valueNinetyNineCorrect()

        allValuesCorrect()
    }

    static beforeInsert = { 
        this.valueOneCorrect=this.valueOne<=this.valueOneMaximum
        this.valueTwoCorrect=this.valueTwo<=this.valueTwoMaximum
        this.valueThreeCorrect=this.valueThree<=this.valueThreeMaximum
        .
        .
        .       
        this.valueNinetyNineCorrect=valueNinetyNine<=valueNinetyNineMaximum
        this.allValuesCorrect=this.valueOneCorrect&&this.valueTwoCorrect&&this.valueThreeCorrect&&...&&this.valueNinetyNineCorrect
    }
}
```

The line `this.allValuesCorrect=this.valueOneCorrect&&this.valueTwoCorrect&&this.valueThreeCorrect&&...&&this.valueNinetyNineCorrect` apparently is producing a NullPointerException because when I comment this line the save process works fine.

In fact lines like this `this.valueOneCorrect=this.valueOne<=this.valueOneMaximum` actually were written using an if-else statement because the operation seems to be producing a `null` instead of a `false`.

Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have a better time getting help, if you include the code that performs the save, and the stacktrace of the error in question.   "A NullPointerException" is almost never enough information.

Comment: The controller and all the CRUD were generated by the scaffolding process.